# How to Flatten Array of Array of custom Object [[CustomModel?]]?

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

I've only basic knowledge in Swift.
I want to change `var dataSource:[[CustomModel?]]?` into `[CustomModel]`.

I tried following Methods

1. let flat = dataSource.reduce([],+)
2. let flat = dataSource.flatMap { $0 }
3. let flat = dataSource.compactMap{ $0 }
4. let flat = dataSource.Array(dataSource.joined())

I'm getting error

*Cannot convert value of type '[FlattenSequence<[[CustomModel?]]>.Element]' (aka 'Array<Optional< CustomModel >>') to expected argument type '[CustomModel]'*

Comment: you can't change the type of the same variable you have to create another 1

Comment: try below answer but as pre to know it's not compiled

Comment: reduce

flatMap 

compactMap return a value and you don't assign it to another variable so your first 3 lines are useless

Comment: @ Sh_Khan I've edited the question kindly have a look

Comment: below is the answer check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
var arr:[CustomModel] = dataSource?.flatMap { $0 } ?? []
```

Also

```
var arr:[CustomModel] = dataSource?.flatMap { $0 }.compactMap{ $0 } ?? []
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to flat the nested array first using flatMap{}, then in order to get the non-optional value use compactMap{}. Suppose the input array is [[Int?]]

```
let value:[Int] = dataSource.flatMap{$0}.compactMap{ $0 } //Correct
```

The other option will give an error -

```
let value:[Int] = dataSource.flatMap{ $0 } ?? [] //Error
```

//Correct
[image]

//Wrong
[image]